# Find Not Null and replace those field with dummy data (large dabatase)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Need to find not null field from tables and replace those field with dummy data for huge database.
I wrote some reference code. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Need to perform more than 10 tables with huge data. Each field with different dummy data not a same. Even solution with mysql also helpful for me

```
Address.where.not(encrypted_address: nil).each do |address|
        address.update_attribute(:address, Faker::Address.street_address)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update_all` which will do a single SQL query.

In your case:

```
Address.where.not(encrypted_address: nil).update_all(address: Faker::Address.street_address)
```

Note this will update all with the same address, and will not trigger any Active record callbacks.

Source: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I need to update each record with different fake data not a same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your operation in transaction `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`
2. load data in batches using `find_each`
3. Load only columns which you want to modify using `select`

```rb
Address.transaction do
  Address.where.not(encrypted_address: [nil, '']).select(:address).find_each do |address|
    address.update_attribute(:address, Faker::Address.street_address)
  end
end
```

If you don't need to call validation or callbacks, you can consider using `update_column` over `update_attribute`

Ideally, Rails is not built for large datasets update. you should consider some native database utilities.